# Можно ли загнать IntStream (Stream API) в System.in

Tags: java, api, потоки-данных

Доброе утро!

Имеется IntStream streamFromString = "Lorem ipsum ....".chars()

Хотелось бы всю эту беду запихнуть в System.in.

Пытался сделать это следующим образом - System.setIn((InputStream) streamFromString);

но вылезает ClassCastException...

Есть ли способ реализовать данную проблему?

Comment: похоже, что проблему вы придумали сами... у вас есть перемсенная в ней записано  "Lorem ipsum ...."., что именно вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: @Дмитрий похоже автор не отключает поток ввода/вывода от потока данных.

Comment: Метод читающий из System.in текст в кодировке UTF-8, подсчитывающую в нем частоту появления слов, - условие реализации использовать Stream API.

Я пытаюсь создать сейчас для себя проверочный пример..

Comment: Stream API никакого отношения к System.in не имеет. и для того, чтобы подсчитать количество повторяющихся слов в тексте вам не нужен System.in. мало того, вам не надо вызывать chars(), потому как это разобьет текст посимвольно, а не на слова. используйте Arrays.stream ("Lorem ipsum ....".split(" ")) - таким образом получите поток , состоящий из слов, а далее коллектором собирайте в Map, где ключ слово, а значение - счетчик повторений. а если уже надо убрать запятые , тире и т.д., то вставляйте map между вызовом стрима и коллектором.

Comment: Решил вопрос вот так

      `String text = "Lorem ipsum ....";
           ByteArrayInputStream textInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
           System.setIn(textInput);`

Comment: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines().

Comment: через System.in не заводят стринговые переменные, это точка входа извне. к примеру, пользовательский ввод с клавиатуры